# Global or Local variable different builder behavior

Tags: delphi, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm still doing practical with llvm-c Api,
I have a doubt about this code:
I got the original code from [source](https://github.com/rogerioag/llvm-gencode-samples/blob/384fa487422d611b51f5530e0dbd58524640fb4c/src/array-1d/C/main.c).
In Delphi is:

```pascal
    procedure test;
(*int A[1024];
int main(){
  int B[1024];
  A[50] = A[49] + 5;
  B[0] = B[1] + 10;

  return 0;
}
*)
var
   context : TLLVMContextRef ;
   module  : TLLVMModuleRef;
   builder : TLLVMBuilderRef;

   typeA,
   typeB,
   mainFnReturnType   : TLLVMTypeRef;

   arrayA,
   arrayB,
   mainFn,
   Zero64,
   temp,
   temp2,
   returnVal,
   ptr_A_49,
   ptr_B_1,
   elem_A_49 ,
   elem_B_1,
   ptr_A_50,
   ptr_B_0      : TLLVMValueRef;

   entryBlock,
   endBasicBlock : TLLVMBasicBlockRef;

   indices : array[0..1] of TLLVMValueRef;


begin
   context := LLVMGetGlobalContext;
   module  := LLVMModuleCreateWithNameInContext('meu_modulo.bc', context);
   builder := LLVMCreateBuilderInContext(context);
//
   // Declara o tipo do retorno da função main.
   mainFnReturnType := LLVMInt64TypeInContext(context);
   // Cria a função main.
   mainFn := LLVMAddFunction(module, 'main', LLVMFunctionType(mainFnReturnType, nil, 0, False));

   // Declara o bloco de entrada.
   entryBlock := LLVMAppendBasicBlockInContext(context, mainFn, 'entry');
   // Declara o bloco de saída.
   endBasicBlock := LLVMAppendBasicBlock(mainFn, 'end');

   // Adiciona o bloco de entrada.
   LLVMPositionBuilderAtEnd(builder, entryBlock);

   // Cria um valor zero para colocar no retorno.
   Zero64 := LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt64Type(), 0, false);

   // Cria o valor de retorno e inicializa com zero.
   returnVal := LLVMBuildAlloca(builder, LLVMInt64Type, 'retorno');
     LLVMBuildStore(builder, Zero64, returnVal);
 //

   // Array global de 1024 elementos.
   typeA  := LLVMArrayType(LLVMInt64Type, 1024);
   arrayA := LLVMBuildArrayAlloca(builder, typeA, LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt64Type, 0, false), 'A'); //LLVMAddGlobal (module, typeA, 'A');
   LLVMSetAlignment(arrayA, 16);

   // Array local de 1024 elementos.
   typeB  := LLVMArrayType(LLVMInt64Type(), 1024);
   arrayB := LLVMBuildArrayAlloca(builder, typeB, LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt64Type, 0, false), 'B');
   LLVMSetAlignment(arrayB, 16);

// A[50] = A[49] + 5;

   // Na documentação diz para usar dois indices, o primeiro em zero: http://releases.llvm.org/2.3/docs/GetElementPtr.html#extra_index
   // The first index, i64 0 is required to step over the global variable %MyStruct. Since the first argument to the GEP instruction must always be a value of pointer type, the first index steps through that pointer. A value of 0 means 0 elements offset from that pointer.
   indices[0] := LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt32Type, 0, false);
   indices[1] := LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt32Type, 49, false);

   ptr_A_49  := LLVMBuildInBoundsGEP(builder, arrayA, @indices[0], 2, 'ptr_A_49"');
     TFile.WriteAllText('Func.II',LLVMDumpValueToStr(mainFn));
   elem_A_49 := LLVMBuildLoad(builder, ptr_A_49, 'elem_of_A');

   temp := LLVMBuildAdd(builder,  elem_A_49, LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt64Type(), 5, false), 'temp');

   indices[0] := LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt32Type(), 0, false);
   indices[1] := LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt32Type(), 50, false);

   ptr_A_50 := LLVMBuildInBoundsGEP(builder, arrayA, @indices[0], 2, 'ptr_A_50');
   LLVMBuildStore(builder, temp, ptr_A_50);
//

// B[0] = B[1] + 10;
   indices[0] := LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt32Type, 0, false);
   indices[1] := LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt32Type, 1, false);

   ptr_B_1 := LLVMBuildInBoundsGEP(builder, arrayB, @indices[0], 2, 'ptr_B_1');
   elem_B_1:= LLVMBuildLoad(builder, ptr_B_1, 'elem_of_B');

   temp2 := LLVMBuildAdd(builder,  elem_B_1, LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt64Type(), 10, false), 'temp2');

   indices[0] := LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt32Type, 0, false);
   indices[1] := LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt32Type, 0, false);

   ptr_B_0 := LLVMBuildInBoundsGEP(builder, arrayB, @indices[0], 2, 'ptr_B_0');
   LLVMBuildStore(builder, temp2, ptr_B_0);
//
     // Cria um salto para o bloco de saída.
     LLVMBuildBr(builder, endBasicBlock);

     // Adiciona o bloco de saída.
     LLVMPositionBuilderAtEnd(builder, endBasicBlock);

   // Cria o return.
     LLVMBuildRet(builder, LLVMBuildLoad(builder, returnVal, ''));

     // Imprime o código do módulo.
   //LLVMDumpModule(module);
   TFile.WriteAllText('Func.II',LLVMDumpValueToStr(mainFn));

   // Escreve para um arquivo no formato bitcode.
   if (LLVMWriteBitcodeToFile(module, 'meu_modulo.bc').ResultCode <> 0) then
     raise Exception.Create('error writing bitcode to file, skipping');
end;
```

the problem is here, if arrayA is a global variable:

```pascal
// Array global de 1024 elementos.
   typeA: = LLVMArrayType (LLVMInt64Type, 1024);
   arrayA: = LLVMAddGlobal (module, typeA, 'A');
   LLVMSetAlignment (arrayA, 16);
....
....
ptr_A_49: = LLVMBuildInBoundsGEP (builder, arrayA, @indices [0], 2, 'ptr_A_49 "');
  TFile.WriteAllText ( 'Func.II', LLVMDumpValueToStr (mainFn));
```

the gep instruction is not transferred to the code, in fact the output is

```
define i64 @main () {
entry:
  % retorno = allocates i64
  i64 0 store, i64 *% return
  % B = allocates [1024 x i64], i64 0, align 16

end:; No predecessors!
}
```

if ArrayA is a local variable:

```pascal
// Array global de 1024 elementos.
   typeA: = LLVMArrayType (LLVMInt64Type, 1024);
   arrayA: = LLVMBuildArrayAlloca (builder, typeA, LLVMConstInt (LLVMInt64Type, 0, false), 'A'); // LLVMAddGlobal (module, typeA, 'A');
   LLVMSetAlignment (arrayA, 16);
.....
....
ptr_A_49: = LLVMBuildInBoundsGEP (builder, arrayA, @indices [0], 2, 'ptr_A_49 "');
     TFile.WriteAllText ( 'Func.II', LLVMDumpValueToStr (mainFn));
```

the gep instruction is transferred to the code, in fact the output is:

```
define i64 @main () {
entry:
  % retorno = allocates i64
  i64 0 store, i64 *% return
  % A = allocates [1024 x i64], i64 0, align 16
  % B = allocates [1024 x i64], i64 0, align 16
  % "ptr_A_49 22" = getelementptr inbounds [1024 x i64], [1024 x i64] *% A, i32 0, i32 49

end:; No predecessors!
}
```

why?

Answer (score 0):

Reply from llvm-dev mainling list

With 'A' being a global variable, the GEP becomes a ConstantExpr
(GetElementPtrConstantExpr instead of GetElementPtrInst) since all of
its arguments are constant. ConstantExpr are "free-floating", i.e. not
int a BasicBlock's instruction list and therefore only appear in the
printout when used.

Michael

## Other user

LLVM has roughly[1] two kinds of Value: Constants and Instructions.

Constants are things like literal constants, (addresses of) global
variables, and various expressions based just on those things; they're
designed to be values that can be directly calculated by the compiler
and/or linker without any CPU instructions actually being executed[2].

Instructions on the other hand sit inside Functions as real entities,
they  produce %whatever Values and, unless optimized away, will be
turned into real CPU instructions in the end.

So, you were asking for "GEP something, 0, 49". If that "something" is
a Constant (e.g. a GlobalVariable) then that GEP only depends on
Constants so it can be a ConstantExpr too, written
"getelementptr([1024 x i64], [1024 x i64]* @var, i32 0, i32 49)". That
Constant is then not inserted into a block (it's not an instruction so
it can't be). Instead it's written directly in any instruction that
uses it, so if you actually use the GEP you might see something like:

```
%val = load i64, i64* getelementptr([1024 x i64], [1024 x i64]*
```

@var, i32 0, i32 49)

Until you use it, it's not actually in the function anywhere though.
You just have a handle when needed.

On the other hand if the "something" is a local variable, then the GEP
needs to be an actual instruction inside a function and the API you're
using will insert it automatically.

In the Constant case, you can manually create an instruction anyway,
at least in C++. I'm afraid I haven't used the C API and couldn't see
an obvious way there, but you probably don't want to since
optimization would quickly undo it and turn it back into a Constant.

Cheers.

Tim.

[1] There's also Arguments, representing function parameters. They
behave like Instructions for these purposes.
[2] But you can build pathological Constants that no linker really
could calculate like 4 * @global. That tends to result in a compiler
error.